# CSS lightbox not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm using this code (http://codepen.io/gschier/pen/HCoqh) for a lightbox for one of my pages (see the page here: http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/press/index.php#_).

For some reason it works fine on desktop but doesn't show the image on my iPhone. You can reproduce the problem by clicking on the first image in the Press area.

There's also another, but less pressing issue, where the background for the lightbox doesn't cover up the rest of the page when I scroll on my iPad. Initially it does, but when I scroll the background seems "locked" in position, revealing the rest of the page underneath. You can reproduce the problem by clicking on the first image in the Press area, then scrolling.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!--PRESS CONTENT-->
    <div class="presscoll">

        <a href="#65Bremner5301-1015"><img src="images/65Bremner5301-1015-thumb.jpg" width="470" class="round press" /></a>
        <!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
        <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="65Bremner5301-1015">

          <img src="images/65Bremner5301-1015.jpg" class="round">
        </a>

        <a href="http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/life-video/style-trumps-amenities-in-summerhill-condo-sale/article13070968/" target="_blank"><img src="images/33-price-video-cover.jpg" class="round press" /></a>

    </div>

                                                                <!--------------------------------------------------------------------> 

    <div class="presscolm">

        <a href="#57alcorn"><img src="images/57alcorn-thumb.jpg" width="470" class="round press" /></a>
        <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="57alcorn">
            <img src="images/57alcorn.jpg" class="round">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/life-video/tour-a-high-end-moore-park-new-build/article13070965/" target="_blank"><img src="images/163-heath-video-cover.jpg" class="round press" /></a>
    </div>

                                                                <!-------------------------------------------------------------------->

    <div class="presscolm">
        <a href="http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/life-video/video-see-how-this-bedford-park-home-sold-for-over-1-million-in-four-days/article12392721/" target="_blank"><img src="images/322-fairlawn-video-thumb.jpg" class="round press" /></a>
    </div>

                                                            <!-------------------------------------------------------------------->


    <div class="presscolr">
        <a href="http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/life-video/how-much-home-does-27-million-get-you-in-forest-hill/article12870916/" target="_blank"><img src="images/204-rosemary-video-thumb.jpg" class="round press" /></a>
    </div>

    <!--PRESS CONTENT-->
```

And the CSS (which I edited to make the images scrollable and zoomable):

```
/** LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/

.lightbox {
    /** Default lightbox to hidden */
    display: none;

    /** Position and style */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;    
    background-color: #fafbff;
    overflow:auto;
}


.lightbox img {
    /** Pad the lightbox image */
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;
}


.lightbox:target {
    /** Remove default browser outline */
    outline: none;

    /** Unhide lightbox **/
    display: block;
}






/** LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include how to reproduce the issue (what to press to show the lightbox)

Comment: No problem, I just did. Thanks.

Comment: Your image has `width="0"` and `height="0"` on iphone. Do you have some js or something that adds it? These are inline attribute on the image tag I am seeing

Comment: I didn't specify the inline height and width before because it was causing problems displaying it. I'll try adding it now that I've adjusted the CSS.

Comment: Try changing your ID so that it does not start with a number

Comment: Actually, there is some javascript I'm using to call on 2x larger images for retina screens. How do I paste that code? You can see the file here: http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/retina.js

Comment: Yes I saw that, it might have something to do with the inline attributes. I bet if you remove that js and test it, it will work perfectly. It's probably because the image is not loaded yet so you get the inline attributes added. It's weird how that works but I am pretty sure that's why

Comment: Yea I see lines like `that.el.setAttribute('width', that.el.offsetWidth);` in retina js which is most likely causing the issue. When that line runs, it calculates the image width as 0 since it is not displayed

Comment: I am done editing my answer, try it and it should work

Comment: Hey Huangism, I fixed this issue by just removing the JS alrogether and making all my images 2x so that they will look good for retina. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your retina.js is causing the issue. When the width and height is calculated, it is returning 0 because the image is hidden.

You can try hiding the image by moving it off the screen. Set `.lightbox` class to display block first of all. Then set these for lightbox class

```
display: block;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
```

then when you click which is the `:target` css, update to

```
.lightbox:target {
    /** Remove default browser outline */
    outline: none;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
}
```

I have tested this on my local and it works on chrome and should work on iphone as well

IMPORTANT - if you are running a retina macbook pro, you can see the same issue on chrome or safari. It's a webkit issue.

Comment: Hey, I fixed the issue by just removing the JS altogether and making all my images 2x so that they will look good for retina. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @AlexBanman although that fixes the issue but it's really a work around. Also now you are loading extra resources for people who are viewing the page without a retina screen. Meaning more loading time, bigger files when unneeded. You should keep the js and apply my solution so you will not lose on performance

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. :/ I just needed a quick fix, and my boss  said he's fine with extra loading time, he just wanted to me to get it done. I'm still pretty new to web coding so sometimes it's quicker to take the easy way out. I'll mark your answer as correct, and refer to it when I need this feature for my own websites. Thanks again!

Comment: I am certain you will eventually be working at a place where load time is important and this trick will come in handy one of these days